# Selenium keywords in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, robotframework

With [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/02/recording-robot-framework-keywords-with-selenium-ide/) solution can i map the Selenium commands to Robot Framework keywords. It works good. But i think its impossible to map all the selenium keywords in the formatters. How can i call Selenium commands in Robot Framework ? In the deprecated library SeleniumLibrary i can call the keyword Call Selenium Apoi. Is there a solution for Selenium2Library ?

I would like this functionality for record a test for Robot Framework with Selenium IDE.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a selenium method, that needs to be called directly?

Comment: Yes as example the keyword Click. In Robot Framework its called Click Element. When i record in Selenium IDE and run it with Robot Framework i received this error: No keyword with name 'click' found. Did you mean Selenium2Library.Click Link. Of course i can map this simple keywords with the solution in the top. But it is impossible to do that for all keywords.

Comment: What I'm asking is an example of a selenium method, that is impossible to match to a robot keyword.

Comment: Its not impossible to do, but selenium has a lot of keywords (http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/introduction-to-selenium-automation/selenium-ide/114-selenium-ide-complete-list-of-commands). It takes a lot of time to do it manually Is there not eassier solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some solutions to convert Selenese to RF+Selenium2Library.

This is a Python converter, [Se-IDE-format-to-Robot-Framework](https://github.com/NeverSmileK57CLC/Se-IDE-format-to-Robot-Framework).

This is a Selenium IDE file exporter [Robot-Framework-Formatter](https://github.com/NeverSmileK57CLC/Robot-Framework-Formatter)

It does the mapping you want, and you may expand it using the Resource file. It would be good if more selenese mappings would be proposed by you (PR).

Comment: The second solution with the resource file is verry simple and works good. But it don't have al the selenium keywords. As example the keyword waitForPopUp is not in the resource file. I would like to have a solution with ALL the keywords. It is impossible to do it manually.

Comment: You really need ALL the keywords?  I've been using SIDE for 6 years now and rarely need or use more than about 20-25% of the available keywords.  If you do need them, you can certainly add them yourself to the formatter (or python version).  The format is simple enough to follow, and a bit of work done in the beginning will mean you have a converter that will convert all the commands you need. I'm sure the developer would appreciate submissions to flesh it out (or you could just fork your own version.  Don't expect to be handed everything on a silver platter.  :)